# Why do the fitted regression lines not appear per group on my scattered plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, regression

I have tried different approaches but I cannot seem to get a fitted line on my plot per group.
Plot ends up looking like the one on the attached photo [image].

This is my data

[image: My data]

```r
#first approach, did not work
df_algaeconsump %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=`Light treatment`, y=Feeding)) +
  stat_smooth(method="loess") +
  geom_point(aes(colour=Group)) +
  labs(x="Light Treatment", 
       y="Algae consumption")

#still nothing 
ggplot(df_algaeconsump, aes(x=`Light treatment`, y=Feeding, color = Group) ) 
   +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", alpha = .15, aes(fill = Group))

#tried with this one hoping it would work but nothing again 
ggplot(subset(df_algaeconsump,Group %in% c("1","2")), aes(x=`Light treatment`, y=Feeding, color=Group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(data=subset(df_algaeconsump, Group=="1"), method="lm" , 
                          se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=subset(df_algaeconsump, Group=="2"), method="lm" , 
                          se=FALSE) +
  xlab("Light Treatment") +
  ylab('Algae consumption')
```

```
   Light.treatment    Feeding Group
1     Treatment 1  0.02416667     1
2      Treatment 2 0.01800000     1
3      Treatment 3 0.01400000     1
4     Treatment 4  0.07450000     1
5     Treatment 5  0.00600000     1
6     Treatment 6  0.02740000     1
7     Treatment 1  0.02660000     2
8      Treatment 2 0.04033333     2
9      Treatment 3 0.00850000     2
10    Treatment 4  0.01175000     2
11    Treatment 5  0.03600000     2
12    Treatment 6  0.01550000     2
```

Comment: It's harder to help you without a reproducible example. Post some example data or toy data that reproduces your issue, if you can. You might try leaving out the `data` argument in `geom_smooth` and instead adding a `group = Group` to `ggplot(aes(...))`

Comment: I have edited my post so it includes the data now. I have just signed up so was not sure how posting and everything works here but hoping someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that if you have an x axis with discrete levels, you need to force the series into groups to allow `geom_smooth` to consider the x axis as a continuum.

Another issue is that your data don't really lend themselves to a `loess`, so here is an `lm` instead:

```r
df_algaeconsump %>% 
  ggplot(aes(`Light treatment`, Feeding, 
             colour = factor(Group), group = factor(Group),
             fill = after_scale(color))) +
  stat_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "lm", alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Light Treatment", 
       y = "Algae consumption",
       color = 'Group') +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you try a `loess` with default settings, you will get two overfit curves, a bunch of warnings and no standard error ribbons:

```r
df_algaeconsump %>% 
  ggplot(aes(`Light treatment`, Feeding, 
             colour = factor(Group), group = factor(Group),
             fill = after_scale(color))) +
  stat_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = "loess") +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Light Treatment", 
       y = "Algae consumption",
       color = 'Group') +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am just getting started on R so still struggling quite a bit but thought R would make data visualisation easier than excel. How would I go about in plotting lines that fit the point? In order to show the contrasting curves between group 1 and 2?